# Gnome-shell and compiz

Tags: 12.04, compiz, gnome

I was using ubuntu 2d till now along with compiz. now i installed gnome-shell and after that compiz effects are not working. Is there any way to get compiz effects to work,else is there any other similar packages?

Comment: have you tried Gnome Shell?

Comment: im using gnome shell

Answer (score 2):

Compiz and gnome-shell do not go hand-in-hands together... Third heading in the link provides more insight about it: https://live.gnome.org/GNOME3Myths

Also the mailing list post about compiz and gnome-shell might be of interest for you:
http://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-devel-list@gnome.org/msg15602.html

So as far as I know, you can't get effects equivalent to those provided by compiz in gnome-shell... You might try to look for the gnome-shell extensions with similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that. was just looking fr someone with links to gnome-shell extentions that provide similar customizions of wobbly window.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal: sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager and then run the program (ccsm) to edit compiz settings.

Comment: i did.. but compiz settings wont work in gnome-shell.
any alternatives for compiz with features like wobbly windows?

Comment: OK, you could also consider using gnome classic, same look and feel as in Lucid and with all the features of compiz (even the wobbly windows ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to type in `compiz --replace` within the terminal? I had to do that for the Cinnamon shell, but I am not certain whether gnome uses metacity or compiz by default.

[edit]:

Or press ALT F2 to open up a command field and then type in `compiz --replace`